# What was Robert E Lee's nickname at West Point?

Tags: american-civil-war

Currently, I am reading "Robert E. Lee: A Biography by Emory M. Thomas." Chapter 3, titled "The Marble Model", describes Lee's military bearing and posture which earned him this nickname. According to the Wikipedia entry for Robert E. Lee, he was known as Marble Man. Was he known as both?

Comment: Why not both? I know among my friends I have more different nicknames than I can honestly count. I've been called *everything* (yes, including that.)